# Integrating a Visual Studio's Interactive C# with a running process

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, read-eval-print-loop

Visual Studio 2015 (Update 1) has a new and awesome feature: REPL based Interactive C# console. This interactive console is ideal for code prototyping and scripting as it is really easy to use due to it's IntelliSense and other goodies.

Now, things could get even better if I could get the interactive console to communicate with a running application of mine. It will be really nice to be able to call a method or change objects properties on the run from the console.

Question:
Does any one has an idea how such a things can be done?

Comment: You can run code while debugging via the 'Immediate Window' (Debug -> Windows -> Immediate). Not exactly what you're asking for, but perhaps close enough.

Comment: @Pieter My main goal is to be able to develop and run scripts that control application while it's running. 'Immediate Window' does allow execution of code in the context of the running application, but the application has to be paused first - not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "communicate with a running application of mine"?What do you want to achieve?

If you want a standalone C# console you could try [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: @KennethK. - shouldn't your comment be a flag rather than a comment?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Touché.

Comment: @MartinoBordin The "communicate with a running application of mine" means I want to interact with my code while it's running. About LinqPad, as far as I understand, it does not allow executing commands in the context of a another application, or does it?